# How to load a pdf file in webview with authentication in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, webview

I want to show pdf in webview in flutter from a url using basic authentication.

I have tried several webview libraries like webview_flutter, webviewx, flutter_webview_plugin etc without success.

for example using flutter_webview_plugin  :

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
            

flutterWebViewPlugin.launch(urlToPdf,
              headers: {'Authorization':'Basic pDLiX5VzZEOLdlkDkDVGMWtYQ2x6bWF5WmK='},
              withOverviewMode: true,
              displayZoomControls: true,
              scrollBar: true,);
          },
          child: const Text('Open Fullscreen Webview'),
```

using the webviwx library:

```
webviewController.loadContent(urlToPdf,
      SourceType.url,
      headers: {'Authorization':'Basic pDLiX5VzZEOLdlkDkDVGMWtYQ2x6bWF5WmK='}
    );
```

do you know of any solution? thanks for your help )

Comment: @blackapps please check updated question

Comment: @blackapps sorry thought it was clear from title. could you please check now if it makes sense ?

Comment: A webview cannot display a pdf document. All in vain..

Comment: @blackapps then what are the other options to show pdf?

Comment: There is a google online service that transforms an online pdf in html so you can show it in webview. Otherwise download the beast and use ACTION_VIEW to let the user choose a pdf viewer app. Your app can also use a library to show a pdf after download. Also therte is the PdfRenderer class.